# How can I use Query notification and what are the requirement?

Tags: sql-server, jsp, tomcat, wolfram-mathematica, query-notifications

I want to use Query notification in our app to get the notification from database for updated data, so that app fire the query to get updated data instead of monitoring the database for every 5 sec. I am using ms sql server 2012 express edition, Is this edition comfortable to use query notification? Am using apache tomcat server to deploy my application(webMathematica), I use user custom tag of jsp to embed my application to tomcat server.

I need to configure client application to send notification request to database, I have no idea how to do that. Suggest me good material/link to use query notification.